# how to implement SCD type 2 in redshift

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

we are getting data as below , creation time column tells us the order of records. need to process the complete batch of records. after processing need to maintain SCD type -2. and maintain active and inactive columns.

```
key data    creation_time (in mili seconds)
k1  abc     2021-09-16 14:17:28.447000
k1  abcd    2021-09-16 18:50:42.676000
k1  abc     2021-09-16 18:50:42.853000
k1  abcd    2021-09-16 18:50:43.141000
k1  abc     2021-09-16 18:50:43.809000
k1  abcd    2021-09-16 18:50:44.288000
k1  abc     2021-09-16 18:50:44.854000
```

output after applying SCD type - 2.

Rule#. order of incoming data is based on creation_time, a new record will only be insert and inactivate previous record when incoming record data has some change and its active_dtmz (till seconds) is incremental value.

```
key data    active_dtmz             inactive_dtmz
k1  abc     2021-09-16 14:17:28     2021-09-16 18:50:42
k1  abcd    2021-09-16 18:50:42     2021-09-16 18:50:43
k1  abc     2021-09-16 18:50:43     2021-09-16 18:50:44
k1  abcd    2021-09-16 18:50:44     3001-01-01 00:00:00
```

key points

1. active-dtmz having till seconds only.
2. ignore if next record is duplicate in terms of data for same key.

Comment: Why does the result set have only 4 rows?

Comment: active_dtmz values doesn't contain miliseconds, that is why there are only 4 records.
this is the requirement that active_dtmz should contain only seconds.

Comment: . . The question needs to be modified (or you need to ask a new question) to clearly explain the logic.  "having till seconds only" doesn't work.  How do you handle multiple rows with the same seconds value?

Comment: sure , i have added few more detail as Rule, please let me know if still you have any question. i need to understand is it feasible or not. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you seem to want `lead()`:

```
select t.key, t.data, t.creation_time as active_dtmz,
       lead(t.creation_time, 1, '3000-01-01 00:00:00') over (partition by t.key order by t.creation_time) as inactive_dtmz
from t;
```

However, there is the mystery of why your desired results have only four rows.

Comment: actually you have considered that active_dtmz is having miliseconds also, but this is NOT the case in expected output that why it is having less rows. 
the only challenge here active_dtmz is having till seconds only. that why it create this problem more complex.

Comment: Gordon, could you please help if you have any idea of doing this.